# How do you check your Xero API usage?

Tags: xero-api

We've recently developed our own application that interfaces with the Xero API. Right now, we estimate we're making 1000 API calls on a busy day. This is well below the 5000 call limit, but we're expanding usage of the application and need to measure how many calls we make per day so that we don't inadvertently hit the limit.

I realise we could record this information on our side (and indeed we do, but it's not retrieval friendly yet as we haven't stood up a data warehouse), but is there a section in Xero where you can see a graph or tabular data of your recent API usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, we don't have anywhere that you can check your usage.

Often people think they're hitting the daily limit but it's actually the 60 calls per minute limit. If you check the X-Rate-Limit-Problem header we send back on rate limit errors you can confirm which limit you're hitting.

Otherwise log a ticket [with support](https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support/) and we'll take a look for you.

Comment: It's certainly something we're keen to provide in the not-to-distant future: https://trello.com/c/LOGS2GkP/16-developer-dashboard